# Unable to authenticate with invalid token error in dingo/api with jwt-auth

Tags: php, api, laravel, dingo-api

I'm using [dingo/api](https://github.com/dingo/api) (that has built-in support for [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)) to make an API.

Suppose this is my routes :

```
$api->group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function ($api) {
            $api->post('checkPhone', 'LoginController@checkPhone');

            //Protected Endpoints
            $api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {
                $api->post('sendCode', 'LoginController@sendCode');
                $api->post('verifyCode', 'LoginController@verifyCode');

            });
        });
```

`checkPhone` method that has task of authorize and creating token is like :

```
public function checkPhone (Request $request)
        {
            $phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');
            if (User::where('phone_number', $phone_number)->exists()) {

                $user = User::where('phone_number', $phone_number)->first();

                $user->injectToken();

                return $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer);

            } else {
                return $this->response->error('Not Found Phone Number', 404);
            }
        }
```

And `injectToken()` method on `User` Model is :

```
public function injectToken ()
        {
            $this->token = JWTAuth::fromUser($this);
            return $this;
        }
```

Token creation works fine.

But When I send it to a protected Endpoint, always `Unable to authenticate with invalid token` occures.

The protected Endpoint action method is :

```
public function verifyCode (Request $request)
        {
            $phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');
            $user_code    = $request->get('user_code');

            $user = User::wherePhoneNumber($phone_number)->first();

            if ($user) {
                $lastCode = $user->codes()->latest()->first();

                if (Carbon::now() > $lastCode->expire_time) {
                    return $this->response->error('Code Is Expired', 500);
                } else {
                    $code = $lastCode->code;

                    if ($user_code == $code) {

                        $user->update(['status' => true]);

                        return ['success' => true];
                    } else {
                        return $this->response->error('Wrong Code', 500);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return $this->response->error('User Not Found', 404);
            }
        }
```

I used `PostMan` as API client and send generated tokens as a header like this :

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5ODkxMzk2MTYyNDYiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9hcGkucGFycy1hcHAuZGV2XC92MVwvYXV0aFwvY2hlY2tQaG9uZSIsImlhdCI6MTQ3NzEyMTI0MCwiZXhwIjoxNDc3MTI0ODQwLCJuYmYiOjE0NzcxMjEyNDAsImp0aSI6IjNiMjJlMjUxMTk4NzZmMzdjYWE5OThhM2JiZWI2YWM2In0.EEj32BoH0URg2Drwc22_CU8ll--puQT3Q1NNHC0LWW4
```

I Can not find solution after many search on the web and related repositories.

What is Problem in your opinion?

**Update :**

I found that not found error is for constructor of loginController that laravel offers :

```
public function __construct ()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
        }
```

because when I commented `$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);` all things worked. 
But if I remove this line is correct?
How should be this line for APIs?

Comment: $api->version('v1', ['middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {
    $api->get('user', function () {
        $user = app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user();

        return $user;
    });
}); check authenticated users like this

Comment: @Jagadesha NH,  I tried it and error `Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header` occurred.

Comment: https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/325 https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/16 check these links

Comment: I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]` to htaccess, but when sent requests to protected endpoint `404 Not Found` error occures.

Comment: @Jagadesha NH, I found that Handle Authorization Header was in .htaccess file of latest version on laravel(5.3.19) so does not need to add it too again. but problem not solved yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier as an Update note problem was that I used `checkPhone` and `verifyCode` in LoginController that has a check for guest in it's constructor.

And because `guest` middleware refers to `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class` and that redirects logged in user to a `/home` directory and I did not created that, so `404 error` occured.

Now just I moved those methods to a `UserController` without any middleware in it's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

updating my config/api.php to this did the trick

```js
// config/api.php
...
  'auth' => [
        'jwt' => 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT'
    ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Always worth reading through the source to see whats happening. Answer: The  is expecting the identifier of the auth provider in order to retrieve the user.

```
/**
 * Authenticate request with a JWT.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Dingo\Api\Routing\Route $route
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request, Route $route)
{
    $token = $this->getToken($request);

    try {
        if (! $user = $this->auth->setToken($token)->authenticate()) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('JWTAuth', 'Unable to authenticate with invalid token.');
        }
    } catch (JWTException $exception) {
        throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('JWTAuth', $exception->getMessage(), $exception);
    }

    return $user;
}
```